# Get iPhone About Information

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get iPhone about information programatically. There is a picture

[image]

I need `Version` and `Modem Firmware`. I can get `Version` by this code

```
 NSProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersionString
```

but I can not get Modem Firmware. 
In other word I want to get `firmware` and `baseband` version of iPhone.

Are there any suggestions? Thanks